# MySQL MEDIUMBLOB is always of same size

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, pdo

I have MySQL 5.1.65 on shared hosting account and I'm running into troubles when inserting image into my images table(InnoDB) which has MEDIUMBLOB column where I want to store image data.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` mediumblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm using PDO to connect to db from PHP 5.2.17. I tried setting 
    `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"`
in my connection as it was suggested in some answers to similar(or same) problem here at SO and on the web but it didn't fix the problem. 
I also checked max allowed packet in MySQL config and it is set to 16,777,216 which should be enough as I don't allow images larger than 5 MB to be uploaded.

I don't know if it is relevant but I'm inserting data inside the transaction in which I do multiple inserts to other tables as well.

```
        $image_params = array(
            "description" => $data->description,
            "image" => $image->getBinary() // Basicaly does file_get_contents() and returns
        );
        $image_statement = $pdo->prepare(
                "INSERT INTO images (description, image)
                VALUES(:description, :image)"
        );

        $pdo->beginTransaction();

        $image_statement->execute($image_params);
        $some_other_statement->execute($params);

        $pdo->commit()
```

In phpMyAdmin when i browse images table, image column always shows [BLOB - 15B] and when i access it I get .bin file containing "Resource id #[id]" where [id] is id of an image.

Thank you, Viktor

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to my problem! `$image->getBinary()` method was returning GD image resource and not actual binary image string so i changed it to:

```
    public function getBinary() {
        ob_start();
        imagejpeg($this->image);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
```

and it works now! 
Lesson learned and I can proceed working on my project! :)